# Changing all column names of a dataframe with the same bit of string

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I change all column or variable names in a data frame (or data.table), i just want to add the string "par" to each column name (seperated by underscore) how can i (use paste() to) do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a data.frame named `df`:

```
colnames(df) <- paste0(colnames(df), ("_par"))
```